# CSS: @media print without external css file?

Tags: html, css, printing, styles, media

I want to print a html page in a specific way under css. But all the @media print examples seem to have an external .css file I want to be able to do it without an external file which means there will be no link rel tag:

```
 <LINK REL="stylesheet" MEDIA="print...
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an external stylesheet but you can how ever do this on the same page as your HTML if you really want to, an example of this would be like so,

**HTML / CSS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <style>
              @media print {

                   /* changes the display property to none on all 
                      p elements when printed */
                   p { display: none}
              }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <p>I'm here when the page isn't printed</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this didn't work, I was guessing that I needed to add something like:<style media="print">

Comment: No this should work, the `style` tags don't need any attributes it's just declaring that we are writing in CSS and the `@media print {}` should work. Make sure that this is the last bit of CSS to load.

Comment: ok I'm gonna have a bit of a play around. Will the css render in Print Preview?

Comment: Yes CSS renders in print preview and using `@media print` will allow you to add / change styles to your elements when it is either printing or print preview.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@media print` query in a CSS style block:

```
<style>
@media print {
   /* print css here */
}
</style>
```

Comment: yeah this doesn't work for me, I must be doing something wrong it's within the right element as Mitchell Layzell's above.

Comment: @like-a-trainee can you report under which browser and version have u tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your closing style tag () has a space between the end of the @media print query and the closing tag.  Like so:

```
@media print {
      stuff {more stuff;}
} </style>
```

Right curly bracket, space, then closing tag.