# how to print table contained in JSP page using print command using either javascript or java?

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page which contains a Form and also a Table .When i click on print button only table should be get printed .please help me out.

Comment: You want the print button in  your browser not to print the whole page you see?  Does not sound like the normal behavior.

Comment: my web page contains a table .. i want to print only table from web page when i click on Print button

Comment: This can be achieved through CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/q/401623/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/355313/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/19533186/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/9840004/1065197 and on and on...

Comment: and in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382108/hide-form-controls-when-printing-an-html-page-with-css)

Comment: CSS method depends on browser support for proper CSS versions, opening the table content in another tab and initiating print will be more feasible.

Comment: how to open in a new tab and print ... please send me link.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to achieve this to open another tab which will only contain that table you want to print. Then on document.load of that pop-up call the JavaScript function `window.print()`

This will open print window from there you can print the contents of pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window event of javascript just call this event when you press the button

```
window.print();
```